# MySQL if statement returns empty or null, then set to 0

Tags: mysql, null, mariadb, subquery

Using MySQL (MariaDB)

***I'm looking to see if a sub-query returns null***, if so I want it to be 0. I cannot get this to work.
The values in this statement should return NULL (they don't exist in my database). What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT 
   (COALESCE(SELECT z.ID FROM bus_values z WHERE (z.BUS_NUM=35 AND z.WORKER_ID=2922882), 0)) AS BUS_ID, 
   XVAL, 
   YVAL, 
   ZVAL, 
   DATE_ENTERED 
FROM data_points WHERE (WORKER_ID=2922882);
```

MySQL is telling me I have a syntax error on the line `(COALESCE(SELECT ...`

I've also tried to use IFNULL()

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a `LEFT` join:

```
SELECT COALESCE(z.ID, 0) AS BUS_ID, 
       p.XVAL, 
       p.YVAL, 
       p.ZVAL, 
       p.DATE_ENTERED 
FROM data_points p LEFT JOIN bus_values z
ON z.WORKER_ID = p.WORKER_ID AND z.BUS_NUM = 35
WHERE p.WORKER_ID = 2922882;
```

Answer (score 1):

From your query, you can try to use `CROSS JOIN`

you can't use a subquery in `COALESCE` function, because there may be multiple rows in the result set.

```
SELECT 
   COALESCE(z.ID, 0) AS BUS_ID, 
   p.XVAL, 
   p.YVAL, 
   p.ZVAL, 
   p.DATE_ENTERED 
FROM data_points p
CROSS JOIN bus_values z
WHERE (p.WORKER_ID=2922882) AND z.BUS_NUM=35 AND z.WORKER_ID=2922882;
```

otherwise, you can try to use `limit 1` in the subquery end.

```
SELECT 
   COALESCE((SELECT z.ID FROM bus_values z WHERE z.BUS_NUM=35 AND z.WORKER_ID=2922882 limit 1), 0) AS BUS_ID, 
   XVAL, 
   YVAL, 
   ZVAL, 
   DATE_ENTERED 
FROM data_points WHERE (WORKER_ID=2922882);
```

Comment: Interesting... I use LEFT RIGHT and INNER joins but have never used a CROSS JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out elsewhere, using a subquery in an expression like this only works if it returns at most one row (which if necessary you can enforce with `LIMIT 1`).

Your syntax error is caused by you needing two sets of parentheses and only having one.  A subquery in an expression must be in parentheses, and the coalesce call needs parentheses.  So simply changing:

```
SELECT 
   (COALESCE(SELECT z.ID FROM bus_values z WHERE (z.BUS_NUM=35 AND z.WORKER_ID=2922882), 0)) AS BUS_ID,
```

to:

```
SELECT 
   (COALESCE((SELECT z.ID FROM bus_values z WHERE (z.BUS_NUM=35 AND z.WORKER_ID=2922882)), 0)) AS BUS_ID,
```

fixes your problem, but if bus_num and worker_id will not identify a unique row, you should select `MAX(z.ID)` or add an order by and limit 1 to the subquery to get whichever id it is you want found.